# Avoiding oracle, OR separating oracles of the same type

Tags: haskell, build, dependencies, shake-build-system

I have the following situation:

- `find-deps` is an external program that is very quick to run, and discovers dependency information, similar to `ghc -M`. Its output is some file `deps`.
- `compile` is an external program that is very slow to run; unlike `ghc --make`, it is very slow even if none of the inputs have changed.

So the idea is to add a Shake rule that runs `find-deps` to produce `deps`, parse it into a list of files `srcs`, and then the compilation rule would `need srcs` to ensure that `compile` is only re-run if any of the sources discovered by `find-deps` has changed.

The tricky part is that `find-deps` needs to `alwaysRerun`, to discover newly-depended-on source files. So now if the `compile` rule depends on `deps` to get the list of files, it will also `alwaysRerun`. The standard solution would be to use an oracle: we can add an oracle that `need`s `deps` and parses it into a list of files, and then the `compile` rule would first ask for that list of source files, and only `need` them. So there is no `alwaysRerun` on the `need` chain of `compile`.

However, in my case, I am not writing a particular Shakefile. Instead, I am writing a library of reusable `Rules` that users can use to make their own main Shakefile. So I'd need to package it up as something like

```
myRules :: FilePath -> Rules ()
myRules dir = do
    dir </> "deps" %> \depFile -> do
        alwaysRerun
        cmd_ (Cwd dir) "find-deps" ["-o", depFile]

    dir </> "exe" %> \exeFile -> do
        srcs <- askOracle $ Sources dir
        need srcs
        cmd_ (Cwd dir) "compile" ["-o", exeFile]
```

But where would I put the `addOracle $ \Sources dir -> ...` part that would `need [dir </> "deps"]` and parse it and return a list of source files? I can't put it in `rules`, because then two invocations of `rules` with different directories will try to install an oracle handler two times for the same type. And I can't make `dir` be part of the oracle question type, because it is a term-level variable so I can't lift it into a `Symbol` index of the query.

And that leaves me with something super-lame like having a `includeThisOnlyOnce :: Rules ()` that the user has to remember to include exactly once in their Shakefile.

So my question is:

- Is there a way to track dependencies (i.e. to avoid running `compile` when no source files have changed) **without involving an oracle**?
- Alternatively, **is there a way to separate oracles of the same type**, by somehow scoping them so that I could add this `Sources` oracle only to the context of each individual invocation of `myRules someDir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to track dependencies without involving an oracle?

Yes - if the output of `find-deps` doesn't change at all then it won't rebuild `compile`. You can achieve that by specifying a `Change` value such as `ChangeModtimeAndDigest`, but that is a global setting. Alternatively, you can put the output of `find-deps` somewhere such as `foo.deps.out` and then call `copyFileChanged "foo.deps.out" "foo.deps"`, which won't update the timestamp if the file hasn't changed.

> Is there a way to separate oracles of the same type?

Not easily and immediately, although I can see why its useful. I can think of two potential routes to solve it:

1. It would be possible to add `addOracleIdempotent` which ignored any errors about adding the same oracle repeatedly. That's a moderately easy change to Shake (essentially set a flag in `Rules` to ignore duplicates).
2. Alternatively, you could try promoting the `dir` to the type-level and ensuring each oracle has a different type. It probably makes your API more complicated and requires type magic.

Of all these solutions, I'd use `copyFileChanged`, as its simple and local.

Comment: I was hoping that adding a scoped oracle wouldn't be too hard, tbh :)

Comment: It's impossible for things to really be scoped, since they all need to be available at the top when checking if anything needs rerunning.